# Binding to a property in another class WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm very new to WPF and I have data binding down in winforms, but I'm about to pull my hair out here trying to simply bind a textbox, to a property.

I'm simply trying to bind my options classes to various controls, the one I'm currently trying to bind is AppCliOptions.CLIPath

I first just want to say I've been at this now for a few days now, spending an hour or so a day trying to figure out what is wrong. However I haven't found anything specific to what I'm trying to do, maybe I'm just overlooking it, or I still don't get WPF and xaml yet, I'm sure it's something simple.

I did see some saying you can't bind to a static class, but my classes aren't static, just my reference to the instance is.

I have a static singleton class, this is an example.

```
public abstract class AppOptionsBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : AppOptionsBase<T>, new()
{
    protected static T instance = new T();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static T Instance => instance;

    protected AppOptionsBase() { }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
public class AppCliOptions : AppOptionsBase<AppCliOptions>
{
    private string _cliPath;
    public string CLIPath { get => _cliPath; set { _cliPath = value; OnPropertyChanged("CLIPath"); } }
    public AppCliOptions()
    {
        //Set defaults
        CLIPath = @"C:\Path\to\CLI.exe";
    }
}
```

My Xaml.cs file

```
public static AppCliOptions CLIOptions => AppCliOptions.Instance;
```

My .xaml file

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding CLIOptions}" Text="{Binding Path=CLIPath}" BorderBrush="Black"/>
```

The textbox text is always blank, if I call the CLIOptions.CLIPath through code I get the default value as expected.
After all the reading I've done I've tried dozens of different ways to try and bind to this, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working by not trying to set the context in xaml.

Window loaded event

```
txtCLIPath.DataContext = CLIOptions;
```

XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCLIPath" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding CLIPath}" BorderBrush="Black"/>
```